# Web App Project, need assistance

Tags: eclipse, web

Can someone please help, im in my first year of college and im stuck on my web development project. On my blog web page I have a list of posts which i need to arrange chronolgically (new post first). We just started arraylists in my programming class but we have not yet covered how to sort them

Were using the PLAY framework for the project consisting of models, controllers, views and routes. I have a Post Class in the models folder and a Blog Class in controllers shown below

```
package models;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity

public class Post extends Model
{
 public String title;
 @Lob
 public String content;

@OneToMany
 public List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
 public String comment;

public Post(String title, String content)
{
 this.title = title;
 this.content = content;

}

 public String toString()
{
  return title;
} 


}


package controllers;

import java.util.List;

import models.Message;
import models.Post;
import models.User;
import play.Logger;
import play.mvc.Controller;

public class Blog  extends Controller
{
 public static void index()
 {
  User user = Accounts.getLoggedInUser();
  render(user);
 }

 public static void newPost(String title, String content)
 {
  User user = Accounts.getLoggedInUser();

  Post post = new Post (title, content);
  post.save();
  user.posts.add(post);
  user.save();

  Logger.info ("title:" + title + " content:" + content);
  index();
  }

  public static void deletePost(Long postid)
  {    
   User user = Accounts.getLoggedInUser(); 

   Post post = Post.findById(postid);
   user.posts.remove(post);

   user.save();
   post.delete();

   index();
  }


  }
```

and this is the html code that displays the published posts

```
    <section class="ui stacked segment">
     <h4 class="ui inverted blue block header">Display Posts</h4>

      #{list items:user.posts, as:'post'}

       <h5 class="ui inverted green block header"></h5>
   <a href ="/blog/viewpost/${post.id}"><i class="external url icon">${post.title}</a>          
      #{/list}
     </section>
```

Im totally lost in terms of the java part and have crashed the project numerous times trying to make it work, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You shouldn't have to sort.  Just start from the end of the list to the beginning so that the latest one is read first.

Comment: Could you be more elaborate? I dont get what you mean

Comment: A comment is entered into the list of comments as they are created, so the newest comments are always at the end.  Thus I would look into reading the list backwards (reading the last item in the list first and working your way backwards).

Comment: Cheers for the input but i got that working, I just had to import collections and do collections.reverse(posts) before they were rendered to the screen